# Radio button selected & <span> updates

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV with a list of radio buttons and a 'selected search' area (a `<span>`). When clicking on the 'selected search' area, a drop down layer comes out and has the DIV with the list of radio buttons. When a radio button is selected, the 'selected search' area is updated with that radio button's text and the drop down layer collapses/disappears.

**Here's my HTML structure:**

```
<div class="radio-btns"><span class="selected-search">A</span>
 <div class="radio-btns-wrapper">
  <label><input type="radio" value="a" id="a" checked>A</label>
  <label><input type="radio" value="b" id="b">B</label>
  <label><input type="radio" value="c" id="c">C</label>
  <label><input type="radio" value="d" id="d">D</label>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how to accomplish this with jQuery? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

## ** EDIT **

Since I asked this question back in 2010 I have now improved in jQuery a bit, so here's a revised markup since the above one isn't ideal.

**New HTML structure:**

```
<a href="#" class="selected-search">A</a>
<div class="radio-btns-wrapper">
    <label><input type="radio" value="a" id="a" name="radio" checked>A</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="b" id="b" name="radio">B</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="c" id="c" name="radio">C</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="d" id="d" name="radio">D</label>
</div>
```

**jQuery script:**

This is an improvement on @Greg's answer below:

```
//If JS is available, hide the radio buttons container
$(".radio-btns-wrapper").hide();

//DIV with radio buttons will slide down when clicking on .selected-search
//The default action on the link <a> is removed (preventDefault();) to avoid having the page jump to the back top
$(".selected-search").click(function (e) {
    $(".radio-btns-wrapper").slideDown();
    e.preventDefault();
});
//Click on radio button and have target text update with radio button's text
$("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
    // Alter the text of the span to the text of the clicked label
    $(".selected-search").text($(this).parent().text());
    // Now hide the radios
    $(".radio-btns-wrapper").slideUp();
});
```

And since the link to demo in the selected answer doesn't work anymore, I created my own demo. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/vyvLvgkh/4/

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Ok, what about it? I read the post and there's certainly no consensus. Also, for what I read "tags" CAN be part of the question title as long as they are meaningful and help the title be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's a JsFiddle with an example**:

<s>http://jsfiddle.net/g105b/VHBkP/</s> (demo appears to have been removed from jsfiddle.net)

Here's a link to a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/vyvLvgkh/5/ - *See edit above for improved markup and new script.*

```
$(".radio-btns").click(function() {
    $(".radio-btns-wrapper").toggle();
});

$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
    // Alter the text of the span to the text of the clicked label.
    $(".selected-search").text($(this).parent().text());
    // Now hide the radios.
    $(".radio-btns-wrapper").hide();
});
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed :) - This looks so simple once it's done, but I just don't know enough jQuery to come up with this myself :p. Lesson learned. Thanks a lot Greg.

Answer (score 1):

this should get you on your way:

```
$('span.selected-search').click(function(){
    this.next('div.radio-btns-wrapper').toggle();
});
```

Check out the docs for options to toggle: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Also note that this will only work if the span you want to show occurs immediately after the selected-search span

Comment: Hersheezy, this part works fine. Thanks a lot for your input.